# How to Create Shortcut with Multiple Target

Tags: vb.net

The ShortCut I want to Create as:

> "C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro\ViceVersa.exe" "c:\users\waseefur.rahman\documents\viceversa pro\test 3.fsf" /autocompare

I have been trying with coding as below:

```
Dim shortcutPathName As String = "E:\VVTest\Z Create Shortcut" & "\MyShortcut.lnk"
Dim WshShell As WshShell = New WshShell
Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut

MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut("E:\VVTest\Z Create Shortcut" & "\MyShortcut.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)
MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro"
MyShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro\ViceVersa.exe"
MyShortcut.Arguments = "c:\users\waseefur.rahman\documents\viceversa pro\test 4.fsf / autocompare"

MyShortcut.Description = "VV Shortcut"

MyShortcut.Save()
```

I am getting the Result as:

> "C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro\ViceVersa.exe" c:\users\waseefur.rahman\documents\viceversa pro\test 4.fsf/ autocompare

i.e without "",
But I need it as:

> "C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro\ViceVersa.exe" "c:\users\waseefur.rahman\documents\viceversa pro\test 3.fsf" /autocompare

Could any advise me Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding escaped quotes where you need them:

```
MyShortcut.TargetPath = """C:\Program Files\ViceVersa Pro\ViceVersa.exe"""
MyShortcut.Arguments = """c:\users\waseefur.rahman\documents\viceversa pro\test 4.fsf"" / autocompare"
```